# Return only incomplete items ToDo List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

Creating a Todo list and would like for the user to only see their incomplete items. Thinking I would alter the following block of code with ifelse statement? I'm not 100% sure how to go about it.

```
[HttpPut(Name = "PutTodoItem")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateTodoItem(Todo todo)
 {
   if (todo != null)
   {
      var existingTodo = await _context.Todos.FindAsync(todo.Id);
      if (existingTodo != null)
      {
        existingTodo.Name = todo.Name;
        existingTodo.IsComplete = todo.IsComplete;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(existingTodo);
      }
```

This is my current ToDos class

```
public class Todo
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public string? Name { get; set; }

public bool IsComplete { get; set; }

  }
```

GET code :

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetTodoItems")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Todo>>> GetTodoItems()
{
    return Ok(await _context.Todos.ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: the method updates todos into database. You need to have GET to return the todos (completed or not completed)

Comment: @sam I think I see what you're saying. I've added my Todos class method. I do have a get; set;  for the IsComplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code snippet above modifies one `Todo` item. You need something like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult<IEnumerable<Todo>>> GetTodoItems()
{
    return Ok(await _context.Todos.Where(t => !t.IsComplete));
}
```

I would recommend you to explore differences between different REST API methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc.).